# Client Side Unobtrusive Validation MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

i am creating a basic web application in which i have made a layout page which is used by view "Default.cshtml" to render two partial views,

1.ViewRight_Form 
  Form to submit student details to a DB

2.ViewRight_Display
  Displays all the records stored in the DB

on click of their respective html inputs, in which they are rendered in a div element "#right". I tried to apply client side validation on "ViewRight_Form" using DataAnnotations but have not been successful.The page doesn't show Validation error and the partial view just disappears.Request your help in this.

1.Default.cshtml

```
@using TestApplication.Models
@model TestApplication.Models.Select

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">




$(document).ready(function () {



    function Save1() {
        $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($("#right"));
        $("#right").load("/Default/Save1");

    };

    $("#Save").click(Save1);

    $("#Display").click(function () {

    $("#right").load("/Default/Display");
    });

});
```

2.ViewRight_Form.cshtml

```
<link href="~/Content/ViewRight.css" rel="stylesheet" />
      @model TestApplication.Models.StudentTable


<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>

    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Save", "Default", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod="POST" }))
 { 

    <div id="main">

        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <h1>Right Partial View</h1>
        <ol>
            <li>
                <div class="label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(t => t.ID, "ID")
                </div>
                  @Html.TextBox("ID")
            </li>

            <li>
                <div class="label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(t => t.Name, "Name")
                </div>
                @Html.EditorFor(t => t.Name)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(t => t.Name)
                @*@Html.TextBox("Name")*@
            </li>

            <li>
                <div class="label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(t => t.Age, "Age")
                </div>
                @Html.TextBox("Age")
            </li>

            <li>
                <div class="label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(t => t.Contact_Number, "Contact Number")
                </div>
                @Html.TextBox("Contact_Number")

            <li>
                <div class="label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(t => t.Division, "Division")
                </div>
                @Html.TextBox("Division")
            </li>
        </ol>

        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </div>

 }
```

3.Layout Page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Test Application</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    <link href="~/Content/DefaultStyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" />


</head>
<body>

    <div class="header">
        @DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek    @DateTime.Now.ToString("H:mm:ss")
    </div>

    @RenderBody()



    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

4.Controller Action

```
 public ActionResult Save(StudentTable temp)
        {
            StudentDB object1 = new StudentDB();

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                object1.StudentRecord.Add(temp);
                object1.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Default");
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Default");
```

Comment: Please add your model class.

Comment: Your layout page has `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")` and `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")`. Start by deleting all the scripts from your main view and partials (you cannot have multiple copies of the same scripts).

Comment: Next remove the `$.validator.unobtrusive.parse($("#right"));` from the `Save1()` function and add `var form = $('form'); form.data('validator', null); $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);` immediately after you add the dynamic content

Comment: Thanks Stephen Muecke , your solution worked.